Do native speakers still use the word “seldom” nowadays on daily conversation?

Do native speakers (American & British speakers) still use the word “seldom” nowadays on daily conversations/writing?

I usually see the word “seldom” on my grammar book or school textbook, but not common on social media.
Ngram:



From the graph, it looks like this word isn’t commonly used by native speakers. I’m not sure if the graph shown above is true or not, so I ask the question above here.

Yes, all the time!

I wouldn't say it's used very often in everyday speech, but it's certainly not unheard of. Other synonyms like "rarely" or "infrequently" are more common, I imagine in part because they can do double duty with their adjective form, while "seldom" is strictly an adverb. "Seldom" strikes me as somewhat formal.

They often write it. And one doesn't hear its synonyms in the news either, unless someone is describing someone's not-usual behavior. So, "in the media", does not mean much here. [see something in a book, not on it, which means on top of it]

Your NGram isn't very useful - particularly because you searched for Seldom starting with a capital letter. NGrams is case-sensitive, so almost all matches will be sentences starting with a "fronted" adverbial clause, such as Seldom do we see this. But that's a "marked, literary" construction compared to We seldom see this, so you're only really charting formal / literary usages. Instead, check out I have seldom seen

The Seldom Scene. https://youtu.be/HxHSQ4R-0pg

While "seldom" isn't exactly a formal word, there are far more informal expressions, such as "not often" that are probably used more in everyday speech. But it certainly isn't an archaic word - I can't remember precisely the last time I heard it, but it isn't jarring so it can't have been that long ago.
I see you used an ngram which can occasionally be useful in comparisons but I recommend caution because the results can be misleading. Your graph, for example, looks like there are upward and downward trends but the fact is that the relative frequency ranged from 0.00006% to 0.00003%. That's the difference between the word appearing once every 1.67 million words, and once every 3.33 million words. The ratio between those numbers would be 2:1. If you went from hearing a word twice a day to hearing it once a day, you wouldn't say the word had fallen from use. The frequency was minutiae to begin with, so the decline is insignificant.
This ngram maps other similar words and expressions over the top of your original result. As you can see, there are slight trends up and down for all of them, but they often overlap meaning they are in use as much as each other, and none have fallen completely from use. The narrative I would give to this data is that there are so many ways to say the same thing that you may not hear one often if those you interact with prefer another.
This second ngram is perhaps the most telling though - I have added in the words "rare" and "rarely" and, as you can see, they are used significantly more than any of the others. I would say that this is the word that is dominantly used and has broad upward trends over periods when the others fell.

FumbleFingers made a good point in the comments about ngrams being case sensitive, so your second ngram would be more accurate if you used this, which still shows a slight decline, but at least the word seldom is more properly represented.
